# Exception thrown: 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbUpdateConcurrencyException' in System.Private.CoreLib.ni.dll

Tags: c#, visual-studio, postman

I created this package assign method:

```
 [HttpPut("api/auth/user/{id}")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> AssignPackage(string id ,[FromBody] AppUser user)
    {
        try
        {
            var newUser = Mapper.Map<AppUser, UserViewModel>(user);

            var userToEdit = await _context.AppUser
            .AsNoTracking()
            .SingleOrDefaultAsync(m => m.Id == id);

            newUser.PackageType = user.AccountType;
           
            if (userToEdit == null)
            {
                return NotFound("Could not update user as it was not found");
            }
            else
            {
                _context.Update(user);
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
                //return Ok(newUser);
            }
           

            UserViewModel _userVM =

              Mapper.Map<AppUser, UserViewModel>(user);

            return new OkObjectResult(_userVM);
        }
        catch (DbUpdateException)
        {
            //Log the error (uncomment ex variable name and write a log.)
            ModelState.AddModelError("", "Unable to save changes. " +
                "Try again, and if the problem persists, " +
                "see your system administrator.");
            return NotFound("User not Found");
        }
     
       
    }
```

The aim of the method is that I input the Account type in postman and the output should be the user view model with an updated Package Type. However when inputting the accountType into `postman` the output is `'User not found'` and the error is `'404 Not found'`.

In Visual Studio the error being shown is the title of the question. unsure what the problem may be (only beginner level experience).

The models being used:

```
 public class AppUser : IdentityUser 
    {
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public string AccountType { get; set; }
        public int? PeriodOrderQty { get; set; }
        public int? TotalOrderQty { get; set; }
        public Guid? APIKey { get; set; }
        public Packages Package { get; set; }
        public Cities City { get; set; }
        public QualificationLevels Qualifications { get; set; }
        public string Token { get; set; }
     
    }

public class UserViewModel
    {
        public string Id { get; set; }
        public string UserName { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public string PackageType { get; set; }
        public int? PeriodOrderQty { get; set; }
        public int? TotalOrderQty { get; set; }
        public Guid? APIKey { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: Try adding a variable to the catch i.e. `catch (DbUpdateExecption ex)` and then inspecting the value to see the exception detail

Comment: `ex {Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbUpdateConcurrencyException: Database operation expected to affect 1 row(s) but actually affected 0 row(s). Data may have been modified or deleted since entities were loaded. 
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.AffectedCountModificationCommandBatch.ThrowAggregateUpdateConcurrencyException(Int32 commandIndex, Int32 expectedRowsAffected, Int32 rowsAffected)`
  
I get an error like this when break pointing the new 'ex' variable in the Catch exception.

Comment: Given that `AppUser` inherits from `IdentityUser` it seems that when you call `_context.Update(user);` there is no `Id`. I suspect that if you check that field it will be 0, as it's coming in as part of the body. EF can't find an entity to update because of this, and that's why you're getting the exception.

Comment: When I break pointed the code again to double check the Id value in all instances was being returned as the Id I passed through into postman, however there are other values like the username etc which remain null, could it be because of this?

Comment: Unlikely. The exception suggests that the data no longer exists in the database or that it can't be found when the method is being called. Heave you tried setting the value for `usertoEdit` and saving?

Comment: Okay never mind I believe you were right it is the ID, it seems to be setting the value to a new ID every time, instead of using the value I input. Any idea on what I can do to fix this?

Comment: I suspect it's happening when you map to the view model. Check the mapping configuration

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given that `AppUser` inherits from `IdentityUser` it seems that when you call `_context.Update(user);` there is no `Id`.

I suspect that if you check that field it will be 0, as it's coming in as part of the body.

EF can't find an entity to update because of this, and that's why you're getting the exception

Answer (score 0):

I was getting this error with SQLite. I suspect it is because change tracker cant properly handle Guid ids in SQLite provider for some reason. I switched to `ExecuteUpdate` from change tracker (SaveChanges) and it worked. Here is what I did:

```
var affectedRows = _context.Companies
    .Where(x => ids.ToList().Contains(x.Id.ToString()))
    .ExecuteUpdate(setters => setters.SetProperty(b => b.IsActive, false));
```

You can look up "EF Core ExecuteUpdate documentation" for more examples.